# how to take incremental backup of 5 specific tables in a oracle database using RMAN

Tags: oracle, database-backups, rman

i have to take incremental backup of 5 specific tables in a  oracle database...i cannot use data pump api as it doesn't support incremental backup...in recovery manager(RMAN) the backup is taken of whole database but i want to have backup if data changes in these 5 specific tables , not all tables in which data changes

Comment: what kind of failure do you want to repair with such a backup and why should it be incremental?

Answer (score 0):

You can take incremental backups of databases, individual tablespaces or datafiles.  So if you only want 5 tables, you could move those tables into their own tablespace and then take backups of just that tablespace.

You would want to be very sure that these tables are "self-contained" in the sense that if you wanted to restore that tablespace to a specific point in time, you would not introduce a logical corruption into the rest of the database.